# UIScrollView contentInset is changing after been set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an iOS app using an UIScrollView (containing an UIImageView). After a zoomscale change and back to 1.0, when I try to change contentInset of the scrollView, , it's changing right after to another value.

How can I enforce the contenInset ?

```
myScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior=UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
float offx=0; // it's actually calculated
myScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, offx, 0, offx);
NSLog(@"Inset just set to:%.0fx%.0f (%.0f)",myScrollView.contentInset.left,myScrollView.contentInset.right,offx);
 // The 3 above values are supposed to be aligned
```

> expected outcome : Inset just set to:0x0 (0)
>   actual outcome : Inset just set to:20x20 (0)

Comment: Does this only happen on iOS 11? Could be related to this: https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/ios-11-preliminary-experience-sharing-51be4de1b7d2

Comment: Couldn't test on iOS 10, but found out that the issue happens after setting the zoom to e..g 0.9 and then back to 1.0 programmatically. The code still sees the zoom at 0.9 when it's actually 1.0 already.